# How can I assign the values using index matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm working in Matlab and I have the following problem:
I have a 2x4 matrix A

```
A = 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0
```

and index matrix

```
index = 1 2
        2 3
```

each row of index matrix indicates the location I want to assign in A. What should I do to make A be

```
A = 1 1 0 0
    0 1 1 0
```

Another Example: if index is

```
index = 1 3
        2 4
```

then

```
A = 1 0 1 0
    0 1 0 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: What about `for i=1:size(A, 1) A(i, index(i, :)) = 1; end`?

Comment: Haha, I have same code with you before but it will be slow when A is large.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [linear indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/) and [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/):

```
A((index-1).*size(A,1)+(1:size(index,1)).') = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! It works and makes my code faster. But I don't know why it work. I will study  linear indexing later.

Comment: Yes, linear indexing can be tricky at first. But it's very powerful and useful